# How to create page like general->about->legal in iphone setting preferences

Tags: iphone, settings, preferences

i just want to create a page in setting preferences like the page which comes after pressing clicking on general -> about -> legal

help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

There is some vagueness in your question: are you looking to have a page in the Settings app to set up preferences or are you looking to have a legal disclaimer (or the likes of it) in the Settings app?

If it is the latter, I would suggest that you investigate a little further on whether if it is appropriate based on the [iOS Human Interface Guideline](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556.).

If it is the earlier, you can read more about it [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Preferences/Preferences.html). It would require you to use a Settings bundle and NSUserDefaults class to access it.